# PostBackTrigger on multiple LinkButtons in an update panel

Tags: c#, updatepanel

I have a search form in an updatePanel which retrieves a list of users in a grid in the same UpdatePanel. The name of each user is a commandLink. I want to make the commandLinks as PostBackTriggers.
But when I do it I get an error at the pageLoad time that the controlId does not exist and its true because the grid of users does not render at the load time but through an ajax call.
Any ideas on how can I make the multiple command buttons in a grid retrieved through ajax call as post back triggers?

Answer (score 1):

When adding the items to the grid, within the `ItemDataBound` event handler, you should register the postback for each specific control (the static identifiers in your HTML declarations are essentially placeholders - not all things repeated in the grid can actually have the same ID). You do this using the [`ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx) method:

> The `RegisterAsyncPostBackControl` method enables you to register Web
>   server controls as triggers so that they perform an asynchronous
>   postback instead of a synchronous postback. When the
>   `ChildrenAsTriggers` property of an `UpdatePanel` control is set to true
>   (which is the default), postback controls inside the `UpdatePanel`
>   control are automatically registered as asynchronous postback
>   controls.

As stated above, using `ChildrenAsTriggers` is a possibility, too, but this is commonly set to false for more stringent management.

Comment: My scenario is a little different :) The links are already working as asyncPostbacks while I want those to be normal postbacks. I have the search form and the grid inside an update panel. The search button brings search data and populates the grid in the update panel. Now the grid has links which are by default asyncPostBack calls means clicking the links sends an ajax calls while I want the links to be normal postbacks for redirection. How can I make the links to da a normal post back?
It is actually giving me a parsing error when an asyncPostback occurs on these links to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Here is the code on asp

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Text="Search" />
  <asp:GridView ID="gvSearchResult" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gvSearchResult_RowCommand" 
                                 OnRowDataBound="gvSearchResult_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnDetail" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("CNIC") %>' CommandName="Detail">
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" Text='<%# Bind("Employee_Name") %>' runat="server</asp:Label>
           </asp:LinkButton>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle"Height="25px"Width="30%" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Ihad to place OnRowDataBound="gvSearchResult_RowDataBound" on gridView and that function looks like below. So I had to register the iterative control in Scriptmanager as PostBackControl in RowDataBound event of GridView.

```
 protected void gvSearchResult_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
                {
                    LinkButton lnkbtnDetail = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkbtnDetail");
                    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(lnkbtnDetail);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```